# Can't write to '/etc/network/interfaces' file in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, file-permissions, ubuntu-12.04

I just want to set to default `/etc/network/interfaces` but I can't because I get a `Permission denied` error when I try to write to it:

```
auto lo  
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: URL to a video is a bad idea. People should be able to see the entire question right here on StackOverflow. Plus, what if the video gets deleted tomorrow? Consider editing your question to include the actual problem.

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu or Linux in general, files inside root **`/`** is **owned by root**. A user would therefore need **root privileges** to access those files.

Since you're trying to write to **`/etc/network/interfaces`** file, you do need to be root or have root privileges. To do so, use the **`sudo`** command which is used to perform file operations on files that the **Root User** would only be allowed to change.

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run:

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

This will open **Gedit**, you can then make the necessary changes to the file.

**Note**: Since **Gedit** is a graphical application, it is **recommended** to run **`sudo`** graphically with **`gksu`**. Therefore, you can also do it this way:

```
gksu gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `sudo` or edit as root